# what is the performance hit on the server by checking if a client side script is included

Tags: javascript, .net

We have a social share bar, that is being included on the top and bottom of the page, it is making a call "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js", and as a result, because it is being resolved twice, (top and bottom) we are getting some JS errors in the console.

So, one idea is to resolve it on the server side, by doing

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(widgetJsKey))
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(widgetJsKey, widgetJs);
            }
```

This works fine, I tested it. But I am just wondering, is this really the best way to resolve this issue? becasue by including this, you are registering the javascript on server side, hence the server is bound to take a performance hit.

Isn't it better, just to put the shareBar on the rail , so that it is not included top and bottom? I'd like to get your input on this.

Thanks

Comment: I'm no .NET guy, but in JavaScript you can just use an if statement to check if something is defined.  `if (yourTwittierObjectThing) { /* it's loaded */ }`